# group typescript files into more than one outFile

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to group typescript files into more than one outFile? I still want to bundle my Typescript, but not into a single JS file, I'd like to group my TS is to several JS files e.g. controllers.js, plugins.js. The TypeScript project options seems to only provide one outfile option.

Comment: You might be able to do this with a build tool like Gulp or Grunt, but you can't have multiple `outFile`s unless you have a different `tsconfig` for each group

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is no default TypeScript compiler behavior. I faced this problem myself when I tried to modularize a TypeScript application.

The solution I have decided to use for that problem:

1. Start using good old _references.ts files again.
2. Don't bundle using TSC (just compile to JavaScript).
3. Parse _references.ts files using a Gulp plugin/function. My idea:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

// Consts
var PLUGIN_NAME = 'reference-parser';

// Plugin level function (dealing with files)
function referenceParser(fileName, prefix, filterParentReferences) {
    var references = [];

    var content = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8');
    content = content.replace(/\/\/\/ <reference path=("|')/g, prefix);
    content = content.replace(/.ts("|')\s*\/>,?/g, '.js');

    function readLines(input) {
        if (input.length === 0)
            return;

        var newLineIndex = input.indexOf('\r\n');
        if (newLineIndex >= 0) {
            var line = input.substring(0, newLineIndex).trim();

            readLine(line);

            if (input.length > (newLineIndex + 2))
                readLines(input.substring(newLineIndex + 2));
        } else {
            readLine(input);
        }
    }

    function readLine(line) {
        if (line && line.length > 0) {
            //console.log('Line: ' + line);

            if (line.startsWith('//')) {
                //console.log('Comment line, ignored.');
            } else if (line.indexOf('_references.ts') >= 0) {
                //console.log('External reference line, ignored.'); // TODO Support this?
            } else if (filterParentReferences && line.startsWith('../')) {
                //console.log('Parent reference, ignored.');
            } else {
                references.push(line);
            }
        }
    }

    readLines(content);
    return references;
}

// Exporting the plugin main function
module.exports = referenceParser;
```

b. Concatenate everything in a Gulp task:

```js
//...

        // Get module source files by parsing the module's _references.ts file.
        var sourceFiles = referenceParser(sourceRoot + '_references.ts', buildJsRoot, true);
        // console.log(sourceFiles);
        var sourcesStream = gulp
            .src(sourceFiles)
            .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true })) // Load TypeScript generated source maps
            .pipe(plugins.concat(module.name + '.Bundle.js'))
            .pipe(plugins.uglify({ mangle: false })) // Minify the resulting bundle
            .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.')) // Write the (merged) bundle source maps
            .pipe(gulp.dest(destinationRoot));
        moduleGulpStreams.add(sourcesStream); // Add the source stream to the stream merger

//...
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond. Yeah I've been thinking about not compiling to one js, and then using post compile events to xcopy to various folders and then batch and minify.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating multiple `tsconfig.json` files. Then run the compiler once for each out file:

```
tsc -p /path/to/first/tsconfig.json --outFile controllers.js
tsc -p /path/to/second/tsconfig.json --outFile plugins.js
```

Comment: As of TypeScript 3.6.3, this seems no longer be valid. A config file is specified using the `-p` switch. Also note that the `--outFile` argument can be set in the config file itself.

Comment: You are right. Updated ^ It seems --outFile is still supported so I left if for clarity: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html